# Apache Camel / String template component / Template Groups

Tags: apache-camel, stringtemplate-4

In Apache Camel, is it possible to use template groups (c.f. https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ST4/Group+file+syntax) using the string-template component ?

I would like to load a template group file to be able to used the named templates defined there and use them in the template file refered to by a string-template endpoint.

There does not seem to be any means to configure the string-template endpoint or component to define where to load a group file.

Any ideas on whether this is possible or not and if so how ?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason for needing the template groups and ST4? According to the [String-Template Component page](http://camel.apache.org/stringtemplate.html):

```
string-template:templateName[?options]
```

Where `templateName` is the **classpath-local URI of the template to invoke**; or the **complete URL of the remote template**.

I would think you could put all your template files in the same folder and treat that as your group.

Comment: Yes there is a reason... otherwise why would I ask ? Its to keep my code clean an prevent duplication. Also I may want to use the same groups in different template endpoints. Anyway, I've tried what you said and didn't work for me. Maybe I got it wrong, if you have a working example its welcome...

Comment: I get the string-template usage to prevent duplication, but the concept of a group isn't necessary when you can put them in a folder and reference them by path. I'm at work so I can't get an example together right now. I will try to get a working example when I get home around 6 EST.